# Why can't I display single post in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I have problem with display single post by id in view.

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

That's the way I'm passing varible to the view.

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
```

And this is how I try to display varible.
The interesting thing is that when I'm trying to display all posts then that is works.

What can be wrong ?

[update with logs]

```
Started GET "/posts/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-31 18:15:43 +0100
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Rendered posts/show.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
[2015-10-31 18:15:43] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the logs?

Comment: Are you sure the post with id 2 has the value for title in the DB?

Comment: Yes, If it was an empty then I got an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show

Comment: Can you add your controller's `#index` and `#show` actions?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easy to debug:

1. add gem 'pry' to your Gemfile
2. bundle install
3. Add to your view

binding.pry

@post.title

At the prompt in your server log do @post or if it never hits this you are rendering the wrong view, or etc...

Comment: Now it's everything ok. I don't know what was a problem. Maybe something with WebBrick ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new, here's how your controller and views should look:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= @post.title %>
```

This is what you need to have to get this working.

If you do as above, and have the relative `Post` object in the database, it should work for you.

If it does not, it suggests a problem somewhere else. A good test would be to use the `Rails console`:

```
$ rails c
$ post = Post.find params[:id]
$ post.title #-> will output post's title
```